# Iterate hash of arrays

Tags: ruby-on-rails, arrays, ruby, hash

```
{"title"=>["111", "222", "333"], "rating"=>["1", "2", "3"], "reviews"=>["11", "22", "33"]}
```

I have data with me from the form in the above format.

Now I want to iterate through this loop so that I can get data in below sequence as per my requirement:

```
["111", "1", "11"], ["222", "2", "22"], ["333", "3", "33"]
```

Actually I have to save each record in my database in the way so that a title, a rating and a review forms one row for my database table.

I have tried many possible solutions with 'each_with_index', key, value hash way, but no luck.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What's the logic behind the transformation?

Answer (score 5):

Assuming every value in Hash is an Array of same length, [`transpose`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Array.html#method-i-transpose) array `hash.values` :

```
hash = {"title"=>["111", "222", "333"], "rating"=>["1", "2", "3"], "reviews"=>["11", "22", "33"]}
hash.values
#=> [["111", "222", "333"], ["1", "2", "3"], ["11", "22", "33"]]
hash.values.transpose
#=> [["111", "1", "11"], ["222", "2", "22"], ["333", "3", "33"]]
```

Comment: Alas this will fail if one of the value arrays doesn't have the correct number of elements (`IndexError: element size differs`).

Comment: true. Since OP did not define such cases, I just went with posted example. But sure thanks for pointing conditions, I should specify this in my answer :)

Comment: Great, thanks for the edit :) You're right about the specifications, I just wanted to point it out since input may not stay well-defined over the course of the app's lifetime.

Comment: Thanks Shivam, I have done this with some other way but you have suggested the simplest way.

Answer (score 3):

While the `transpose` solution is very nice, it will error out when not all value arrays have the same number of elements. This will still work (replacing missing elements with `nil`):

```
h.values.reduce(:zip).map(&:flatten)
#=> [["111", "1", "11"], ["222", "2", "22"], ["333", "3", "33"]]
```

If you know that your input is well-formed, go for the `transpose` option.